# How to filter the values from selected columns and rows?

Tags: awk

How can I filter the values from the input files using the row names from ids.1 file and the column names from ids.2 file?

**sample input**

```
name    s1  s2  s3  s4
a1  7   8   7   8
a2  7   54  7   8
a3  8   8   8   8
a4  7   7   7   0
```

**ids.1**

```
name
a1
a4
```

**ids.2**

```
name
s3
s4
```

**sample output**

```
name    s3  s4
a1  7   8
a4  7   0
```

I was using the following code to filter the values of selected rows. How can I extend this to columns as well?

```
awk 'ARGIND == 1 { a[$1] = 1; next } a[$1] { print $0 }' ids.1 sample.input


name    s1      s2      s3      s4
a1      7       8       7       8
a4      7       7       7       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one assumes, that the first record is always in the columns file (ids.2):

```
$ awk '
ARGIND==1 {                  # first file, rows
    r[$1]
} 
ARGIND==2 {                  # second file, columns
    c[$1]
} 
ARGIND==3 && FNR==1 {        # first record of third file, data
    n=split($0,a)            # split the first record to a, the column template
    for(i in a)              # delete the cols we don t want
        if((a[i] in c)==0)
            delete a[i]
}ARGIND==3 && $1 in r {      # third file and the rows we want
    b=""                     # print buffer
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)       # for all cols
    if(i in a)               # get the ones we want
        b=b (b==""?"":OFS) $i
    print b                  # output
}' ids.1 ids.2 file
name s3 s4
a1 7 8
a4 7 0
```

Answer (score 2):

a simpler and faster version:

```
awk '
ARGIND==1{row[$1]=1;next}
ARGIND==2{col[$1]=1;next}
row[$1]{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(col[$i] && FNR==1) v[i]=1
        if (v[i]) printf "%s%s", (i==1?"":FS), $i
    }
    print ""
} ' id.1 id.2 data.file
```

With your example, it gives:

```
name  s3  s4    
a1    7   8   
a4    7   0
```

Comment: Thanks it is more simpler . But, the script marked as answer is 4 minutes faster on a data matrix with 1 million rows and 1k columns. :)